# Font Awesome NuGet Package 3.2.1

Tags: nuget, font-awesome

Is there something wrong with the Font Awesome 3.2.1 NuGet package? When I upgraded from 3.1.1 to 3.2.1 all the fonts stopped displaying. If I link directly to Font Awesome via BootstrapCDN (http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by incorrect relative paths in the CSS. To correct this, update the following files like so (this assumes that the font directory is a subdirectory of where your Font Awesome CSS files are located):

**font-awesome.css, line 28-34:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**font-awesome.min.css, line 1:**

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');src:url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'),url('font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'),url('font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'),url('font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}[class^="icon-"],[class*=" icon-"]{font-family:FontAwesome;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:inherit;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;*margin-right:.3em;}
```

Of course, this defeats the point of using NuGet packages, but consider it a temporary workaround until the package is fixed. It probably doesn't help that there are *two* FontAwesome NuGet packages to choose from, but I would assume once fixed, the package created by [Dave Gandy](https://twitter.com/byscuits) will supercede the one created by JiveCode.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good workaround. The package created by JiveCode is 3.1.1, and I need the new icons defined in 3.2.1

Answer (score 1):

It's likely because the import path in the font-awesome CSS file is wrong for the way the NuGet package inserts the files.  Problem I'm having is it's dumped all the files into the same directory but the import path assumes the CSS files are in their own directory within the directory that the fonts directory is in.

I'm feeling fairly sure it is indeed an issue with the package.